# Cannot create Android Emulators older than Android Kit Kat (4.4)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-manager, android-device-manager

I am trying to create an Android emulator for `Jelly Bean` or `Ice Cream Sandwich` but it doesn't show in the list of available SDK's

[image]

I have installed the System Images and I have tried all four available processors `x86`, `x86_x64`, `armeabi-v7a` and `arm64-v8a` and still, the SDK's are not becoming available.

[image]

Is there a setting I can set somewhere which will allow me to create a simulator for those two SDK's?

Comment: I also sit with the same issue, need to test an app on Jelly bean, I don't have a device and also cannot create an emulator for it with the new version of **Android Device Manager**

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed now in the latest versions of Visual Studio 2019